# Adding a plugin questions

Tags: discussion

Look at the following question: [Adding emmet plugin to Vim in Windows](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/586/adding-emmet-plugin-to-vim-in-windows)

It seems as if the asker doesn't know how to install a pluign, and though asked a specific question for the plugin he tried to install.

I think we should have a question about how to install plugins, with a detailed answer for different version and OS, and reference all question of the type I referenced above to that question.

More generally talking - we should have a few basic and common "howtos" questions of this kind.

Comment: It came up in the "First post" review queue, and I considered (drastically) editing the post to make it a general "how do I install a Vim plugin?"-question, but decided against it because 1) it might confuse the OP, who seems to be a beginner, and 2) didn't want to hijack the question...  But yeah, that would definitely be a good question to have, either as an edit to this one, or as a different question. Why don't you go and ask it? ;-)

Comment: Perhaps a good title for such a question might be: *"What do the different files in a Vim plugin do and how do I install a Vim plugin?"* ... Could maybe also be split in 2 questions?

Comment: I'd be wary of asking the more general question because I'd be worried about it being closed as a duplicate, as happened here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/653/set-an-option-dependent-on-the-filetype?lq=1